# Read Text File Line by Line and Take Input from what ever proceeds '='

Tags: vb.net

newbie question but I can't seem to find a definitive way to do this. I want the program to be able to take information from particular lines of text files and use that information for a variety of tasks. I'd really appreciate it if you could also teach me how to write to a particular line of the text file.

Here's an example of the text file:

> Line1 Name = Garry
>
> Line2 Set = 0
>
> Line3 Other = Other
>
> Plus many more lines

The tricky part is to grab the information that comes after the '=' on line 2 for example. And also if the user wanted to change one of the information on these lines, how I'd go around changing it... I would appreciate any help what so ever.

*Using Visual Basic Studio 2012 on .net 4.5

Comment: Please show what you tried so far

Comment: it looks a bit like an .ini file. look for some libraries to manipulate ini files like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20120/INI-Files or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21896/INI-Reader-Writer-Class-for-C-VB-NET-and-VBScript

Comment: Do you have control over the file and how its laid out?

Comment: I have full control over the file, it's laid out exactly as I have shown above.

Comment: streamwriter for writing the file, streamreader for reading the file, and string.Split for unwinding the lines into data.  Or just write a proper class using List(of T) or similar and serialize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you want to do it simply:

First read all lines of the file

```
Dim Lines() as String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\myfile.txt")
```

The array then contains elements for each line in the file.

Then iterate through these lines:

```
Dim MyKeyValues As New Dictionary(Of String, String) 'See below
For each line as String in Lines
  Dim LineParts() as String = Strings.Split(line, "=", 2) 'Split the current line into two chunks at the first =
  If LineParts.Count < 2 Then
    Continue For 'No = in the line, so skip it
  Else
    Dim Key as String = LineParts(0)
    Dim Value as String = LineParts(1) 'This contains the part after the =
    'Do whatever you want with the value here. e.g.
    MyKeyValues.Add(Key, Value) 'See below
  Endif
Next
```

You can for example save the line parts into a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` and make the changes to the values in this dictionary. Afterwards write the dictionary back to the file:

```
Dim FileLines as New List(Of String)
For each k as String in MyKeyValues.Keys
  FileLines.Add(k & "=" & MyKeyValues(k))
Next
IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\myfile.txt", FileLines)
```

The ReadAllLines() and WriteAllLines() methods should be reasonably fast if the textfile is not extremely large. As others have pointed out an INIFile class should be most suitable for your needs since this makes it easy to read and change keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to an INI file except without headers.

Here is an example of an INI file:

```
[CONFIG]                Header
Option1=true            Key=Value
Option2=true            Key=Value
Option3=false           Key=Value
```

You can read and write to INI files easily by using this class in your project:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class IniFile
' List of IniSection objects keeps track of all the sections in the INI file
Private m_sections As Hashtable

' Public constructor
Public Sub New()
    m_sections = New Hashtable(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
End Sub

' Loads the Reads the data in the ini file into the IniFile object
Public Sub Load(ByVal sFileName As String, Optional ByVal bMerge As Boolean = False)
    If Not bMerge Then
        RemoveAllSections()
    End If
    '  Clear the object... 
    Dim tempsection As IniSection = Nothing
    Dim oReader As New StreamReader(sFileName)
    Dim regexcomment As New Regex("^([\s]*#.*)", (RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    ' Broken but left for history
    'Dim regexsection As New Regex("\[[\s]*([^\[\s].*[^\s\]])[\s]*\]", (RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    Dim regexsection As New Regex("^[\s]*\[[\s]*([^\[\s].*[^\s\]])[\s]*\][\s]*$", (RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    Dim regexkey As New Regex("^\s*([^=\s]*)[^=]*=(.*)", (RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    While Not oReader.EndOfStream
        Dim line As String = oReader.ReadLine()
        If line <> String.Empty Then
            Dim m As Match = Nothing
            If regexcomment.Match(line).Success Then
                m = regexcomment.Match(line)
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Skipping Comment: {0}", m.Groups(0).Value))
            ElseIf regexsection.Match(line).Success Then
                m = regexsection.Match(line)
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Adding section [{0}]", m.Groups(1).Value))
                tempsection = AddSection(m.Groups(1).Value)
            ElseIf regexkey.Match(line).Success AndAlso tempsection IsNot Nothing Then
                m = regexkey.Match(line)
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Adding Key [{0}]=[{1}]", m.Groups(1).Value, m.Groups(2).Value))
                tempsection.AddKey(m.Groups(1).Value).Value = m.Groups(2).Value
            ElseIf tempsection IsNot Nothing Then
                '  Handle Key without value
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Adding Key [{0}]", line))
                tempsection.AddKey(line)
            Else
                '  This should not occur unless the tempsection is not created yet...
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Skipping unknown type of data: {0}", line))
            End If
        End If
    End While
    oReader.Close()
End Sub

' Used to save the data back to the file or your choice
Public Sub Save(ByVal sFileName As String)
    Dim oWriter As New StreamWriter(sFileName, False)
    For Each s As IniSection In Sections
        Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Writing Section: [{0}]", s.Name))
        oWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("[{0}]", s.Name))
        For Each k As IniSection.IniKey In s.Keys
            If k.Value <> String.Empty Then
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Writing Key: {0}={1}", k.Name, k.Value))
                oWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}={1}", k.Name, k.Value))
            Else
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Writing Key: {0}", k.Name))
                oWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", k.Name))
            End If
        Next
    Next
    oWriter.Close()
End Sub

' Gets all the sections
Public ReadOnly Property Sections() As System.Collections.ICollection
    Get
        Return m_sections.Values
    End Get
End Property

' Adds a section to the IniFile object, returns a IniSection object to the new or existing object
Public Function AddSection(ByVal sSection As String) As IniSection
    Dim s As IniSection = Nothing
    sSection = sSection.Trim()
    ' Trim spaces
    If m_sections.ContainsKey(sSection) Then
        s = DirectCast(m_sections(sSection), IniSection)
    Else
        s = New IniSection(Me, sSection)
        m_sections(sSection) = s
    End If
    Return s
End Function

' Removes a section by its name sSection, returns trus on success
Public Function RemoveSection(ByVal sSection As String) As Boolean
    sSection = sSection.Trim()
    Return RemoveSection(GetSection(sSection))
End Function

' Removes section by object, returns trus on success
Public Function RemoveSection(ByVal Section As IniSection) As Boolean
    If Section IsNot Nothing Then
        Try
            m_sections.Remove(Section.Name)
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
    Return False
End Function

'  Removes all existing sections, returns trus on success
Public Function RemoveAllSections() As Boolean
    m_sections.Clear()
    Return (m_sections.Count = 0)
End Function

' Returns an IniSection to the section by name, NULL if it was not found
Public Function GetSection(ByVal sSection As String) As IniSection
    sSection = sSection.Trim()
    ' Trim spaces
    If m_sections.ContainsKey(sSection) Then
        Return DirectCast(m_sections(sSection), IniSection)
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function

'  Returns a KeyValue in a certain section
Public Function GetKeyValue(ByVal sSection As String, ByVal sKey As String) As String
    Dim s As IniSection = GetSection(sSection)
    If s IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim k As IniSection.IniKey = s.GetKey(sKey)
        If k IsNot Nothing Then
            Return k.Value
        End If
    End If
    Return String.Empty
End Function

' Sets a KeyValuePair in a certain section
Public Function SetKeyValue(ByVal sSection As String, ByVal sKey As String, ByVal sValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim s As IniSection = AddSection(sSection)
    If s IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim k As IniSection.IniKey = s.AddKey(sKey)
        If k IsNot Nothing Then
            k.Value = sValue
            Return True
        End If
    End If
    Return False
End Function

' Renames an existing section returns true on success, false if the section didn't exist or there was another section with the same sNewSection
Public Function RenameSection(ByVal sSection As String, ByVal sNewSection As String) As Boolean
    '  Note string trims are done in lower calls.
    Dim bRval As Boolean = False
    Dim s As IniSection = GetSection(sSection)
    If s IsNot Nothing Then
        bRval = s.SetName(sNewSection)
    End If
    Return bRval
End Function

' Renames an existing key returns true on success, false if the key didn't exist or there was another section with the same sNewKey
Public Function RenameKey(ByVal sSection As String, ByVal sKey As String, ByVal sNewKey As String) As Boolean
    '  Note string trims are done in lower calls.
    Dim s As IniSection = GetSection(sSection)
    If s IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim k As IniSection.IniKey = s.GetKey(sKey)
        If k IsNot Nothing Then
            Return k.SetName(sNewKey)
        End If
    End If
    Return False
End Function

' Remove a key by section name and key name
Public Function RemoveKey(ByVal sSection As String, ByVal sKey As String) As Boolean
    Dim s As IniSection = GetSection(sSection)
    If s IsNot Nothing Then
        Return s.RemoveKey(sKey)
    End If
    Return False
End Function

' IniSection class 
Public Class IniSection
    '  IniFile IniFile object instance
    Private m_pIniFile As IniFile
    '  Name of the section
    Private m_sSection As String
    '  List of IniKeys in the section
    Private m_keys As Hashtable

    ' Constuctor so objects are internally managed
    Protected Friend Sub New(ByVal parent As IniFile, ByVal sSection As String)
        m_pIniFile = parent
        m_sSection = sSection
        m_keys = New Hashtable(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    End Sub

    ' Returns all the keys in a section
    Public ReadOnly Property Keys() As System.Collections.ICollection
        Get
            Return m_keys.Values
        End Get
    End Property

    ' Returns the section name
    Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_sSection
        End Get
    End Property

    ' Adds a key to the IniSection object, returns a IniKey object to the new or existing object
    Public Function AddKey(ByVal sKey As String) As IniKey
        sKey = sKey.Trim()
        Dim k As IniSection.IniKey = Nothing
        If sKey.Length <> 0 Then
            If m_keys.ContainsKey(sKey) Then
                k = DirectCast(m_keys(sKey), IniKey)
            Else
                k = New IniSection.IniKey(Me, sKey)
                m_keys(sKey) = k
            End If
        End If
        Return k
    End Function

    ' Removes a single key by string
    Public Function RemoveKey(ByVal sKey As String) As Boolean
        Return RemoveKey(GetKey(sKey))
    End Function

    ' Removes a single key by IniKey object
    Public Function RemoveKey(ByVal Key As IniKey) As Boolean
        If Key IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                m_keys.Remove(Key.Name)
                Return True
            Catch ex As Exception
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

    ' Removes all the keys in the section
    Public Function RemoveAllKeys() As Boolean
        m_keys.Clear()
        Return (m_keys.Count = 0)
    End Function

    ' Returns a IniKey object to the key by name, NULL if it was not found
    Public Function GetKey(ByVal sKey As String) As IniKey
        sKey = sKey.Trim()
        If m_keys.ContainsKey(sKey) Then
            Return DirectCast(m_keys(sKey), IniKey)
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    ' Sets the section name, returns true on success, fails if the section
    ' name sSection already exists
    Public Function SetName(ByVal sSection As String) As Boolean
        sSection = sSection.Trim()
        If sSection.Length <> 0 Then
            ' Get existing section if it even exists...
            Dim s As IniSection = m_pIniFile.GetSection(sSection)
            If s IsNot Me AndAlso s IsNot Nothing Then
                Return False
            End If
            Try
                ' Remove the current section
                m_pIniFile.m_sections.Remove(m_sSection)
                ' Set the new section name to this object
                m_pIniFile.m_sections(sSection) = Me
                ' Set the new section name
                m_sSection = sSection
                Return True
            Catch ex As Exception
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

    ' Returns the section name
    Public Function GetName() As String
        Return m_sSection
    End Function

    ' IniKey class
    Public Class IniKey
        '  Name of the Key
        Private m_sKey As String
        '  Value associated
        Private m_sValue As String
        '  Pointer to the parent CIniSection
        Private m_section As IniSection

        ' Constuctor so objects are internally managed
        Protected Friend Sub New(ByVal parent As IniSection, ByVal sKey As String)
            m_section = parent
            m_sKey = sKey
        End Sub

        ' Returns the name of the Key
        Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String
            Get
                Return m_sKey
            End Get
        End Property

        ' Sets or Gets the value of the key
        Public Property Value() As String
            Get
                Return m_sValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                m_sValue = value
            End Set
        End Property

        ' Sets the value of the key
        Public Sub SetValue(ByVal sValue As String)
            m_sValue = sValue
        End Sub
        ' Returns the value of the Key
        Public Function GetValue() As String
            Return m_sValue
        End Function

        ' Sets the key name
        ' Returns true on success, fails if the section name sKey already exists
        Public Function SetName(ByVal sKey As String) As Boolean
            sKey = sKey.Trim()
            If sKey.Length <> 0 Then
                Dim k As IniKey = m_section.GetKey(sKey)
                If k IsNot Me AndAlso k IsNot Nothing Then
                    Return False
                End If
                Try
                    ' Remove the current key
                    m_section.m_keys.Remove(m_sKey)
                    ' Set the new key name to this object
                    m_section.m_keys(sKey) = Me
                    ' Set the new key name
                    m_sKey = sKey
                    Return True
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                End Try
            End If
            Return False
        End Function

        ' Returns the name of the Key
        Public Function GetName() As String
            Return m_sKey
        End Function
    End Class
    ' End of IniKey class
End Class
' End of IniSection class
End Class
```

Here is an example of how to use this class:

```
Private Sub WriteValuesToIniFile()
    Dim IniFileConfig As New IniFile
    IniFileConfig.Load("C:\User\SumGuy\Desktop\Config.ini")
    IniFileConfig.SetKeyValue("CONFIG", "Key1", "Value")
    IniFileConfig.Save("C:\User\SumGuy\Desktop\Config.ini")
End Sub
```

This will write this to an ini file:

```
[CONFIG]
Key1=Value
```